# Audio player on website

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio-player

I need an audio player on my web page, where there should be a list of songs, and when I click play on an song from the list it should start playing.

I need your advice, what can I use? I am more inclined on using `JavaScript` libraries.

Player example:
[image: Player example]

Comment: Vladja , tried anything yet?

Comment: No, I need an advice from community what to use.  I didn't have an expierence with audio players before. I have an idea about creating playlist, but nothing concrete

Comment: Java is the best way out

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the html5  tag.

Something like:

```
<audio id="themeMusic" controls  autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">  
                    <source src="music/yourfile.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
```

and u can controll it with javascript

```
var music = document.getElementById("themeMusic");
music.play();
music.pause();
```